# silverstripe does not pick up changes in language yml files

Tags: silverstripe

silverstripe does not seem to pick up changes in the language yml files. This used to work. As usual I am doing ?flush=all after the files are changed...

In the templates I am using the t- function like <%t General.GoToPortfolio "zum Portfolio" %>
I was editing existing entries, but the template always shows the old 'version' of the entry. If I remove the en.yml file then the translations are really gone. So I am assuming it works at least a little bit...

At the moment I am using silverstripe 3.1.12
The files are saved here e.g.: module/lang/en.yml

Thanks,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found it:
deleted the contents of silverstripe-cache folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problems some time ago with german umlauts and wrong encoding of the files. So either tell your editor or IDE to encode and write proper utf-8 (best without bom) or htmlencode your umlauts.